# How to share the same model on another AWS Instance

Tags: python, django

I want to write my first Python program using Django. The site will be hosted on Amazon. However my API will use Django and Piston sitting on another instance. I don’t want to have to replicate my Models across two servers. How can I get the API to share the same model as the main Django instance, or should I?

Comment: What do you mean by "replicate my Models"?

Comment: do i have to reproduce the models on both servers if the all connect to the same DB?

Comment: The model code is necessary on both servers for the application to know how to interact with the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing the same data models twice you can create a small django app (which will contain the model definition and logic) as a python module and install it on both the two servers / apps.

Comment: would that mean that on updates of the model I would need to update the both servers with the new app?

Comment: Can I not just auto generate the models from the database they both share?

Comment: @Spike updating a python package is much easier than that (pip install package==1.x)